# I want to know if an item with a specific ID is removed from node

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a node, where users make an entry. This entry can be removed (deleted) by someone else. How can I get notified when an item with a specific ID is removed from the node?

I nedd kind of a Listener probably. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database, Realtime or Firestore?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is using a ValueEventListener if it's Realtime Database or a Snapshotlistener if you're using Firestore and you could also use CloudFunctions if you wanted. Please have a look at the Firebase documentation for the database you're using to get a better understanding. Firebase Documentation:https://firebase.google.com/docs

Comment: What do u mean by notify? Do you want to get and email or something outside your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if an item with a specific ID is removed from node

You can use `ChildEventListener` for that. Beside that fact that you'll know when an item is deleted, you'll be also noticed when an item is added, changed or moved.

```
ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        //Code the see which item is added
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        //Code the see which item is changed
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //Code the see which item is removed
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        //Code the see which item is moved
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```